# How do I do a safe test and set using Doctrine and Symfony transaction?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'd like to understand how to do a safe "test and set" operation with Doctrine and Symfony.

I'm building a meeting scheduling system. I have an entities called

MeetingTime, Teacher and Student

MeetingTime has, among other things, a nullable many to one relationship with Student and a many to one with Teacher.

I want to enforce that the student property of meetingTime can only be saved if the properly is currently null. i.e., one student shouldn't be able to overwrite another. The first student to book the time wins. It seems like a transaction will do this.

I'm doing this:

```
  $saved = true;

  try
  {
    $em->transactional(function($em) use($mtId, $student) {
      $mt = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:MeetingTime')->find($mtId);
      if (is_null($mt->getStudent()))
      {
        $mt->setStudent($student);
        $em->persist($mt);
      }
      else
      {
        throw new Exception();
      }
    });
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
    $saved = false;
  }

  if (!$saved)
  {
// flash "Sorry,, somebody else just grabbed that time".         
  }
```

My UI will cope with most of this by not showing a "Book this time" button on the page if that time is taken but of course the database has the final say if two people do it at the same time.

That seems to work but is this the right way to do it?  Is it transactionally safe?

I implemented it first with an additional "Booking" entity with a one to one to MeetingTime and a many to one with Student and a unique constraint on MeetingTime. That works okay but having Student as a property of MeetingTime is better because I also want MeetingTime to have a unique constraint on Student and Teacher combined because a student can only book one meeting with a teacher.

I know I should probably create my own Exception class so that I know the type of exception. I should also allow it to be happy if the correct student is already set.

In case it matters, the database is PostgreSQL. I'm sure this could be done very efficiently with a trigger but ... that's a whole world I haven't been into and it would be nice to keep this db agnostic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction is not going to help here.  All it does it ensure that the flush succeeds.  It does not lock anything.

Read through here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html

You will probably want to use optimistic locking which only requires adding a version number to your table and flagging it with an @Version tag.  And viola!  No more concurrency issues though you do need to be prepared to catch a possible exception when you flush.

And consider putting the null check inside of $mt->setStudent so it always happens.

Comment: Thanks. I should have known that :)  It's working well. Tricky thing to test but I tested it using two browsers and temporarily inserting some sleep() time for one user.

Comment: Take a look at automated functional testing.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/insulating_clients.html Manual browser based testing is always iffy.  What happens if you tweak the code months from now?  Going to set up two browsers again? In the ideal world you should be able to kick off a bunch of tests every time you make changes.

Comment: Yes, I know you're right. I will look at automated testing soon.

Answer (score 0):

Have the repository look for a MeetingTime entity with both the ID and a null student. If you find one, then you can set the student. Otherwise tell the student they're out of luck.

You'd likely have to make your own repository class for this, if you haven't already.

Unless you have a LOT of students all booking at the same time, I doubt it will be a concurrency problem.

Doctrine also has a pessimistic locking option, but there are quite a few caveats: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#pessimistic-locking

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you reject the optimistic locking approach?  Adding a single version attribute seems a small price to pay for an actual concurrency solution.

Comment: I'm not an optimistic person. :-) Actually it's not really a lock, it's just a different race condition. So same problem, different column. It helpfully throws an exception, but it has to do another read before the write, potentially adding to the concurrency problem by slowing things down. Also, like tetranz says, hard to test. Pessimistic lock is best, but requires care to implement.

Comment: Nope.  It is a lock.  The trick behind optimistic locking is that is uses something like:  "UPDATE meetingTime SET student = 'Paul' WHERE version = 27;"  If the version has changed then no update and an exception is thrown. The database always locks the table during update operations. But it's all internal.  No additional query required.  Easy to test.

Comment: "UPDATE meetingTime SET student = 'Paul', version = version + 1 WHERE version = 27;"